# Add and remove Class no funcionan JavaScript

Tags: javascript

No puedo borrar ni agregar una clase a mi div.

Este es mi div

```
<div class="not-found md:mb-[500px] mb-[250px] mt-[50px] relative hidden">
   <img class="not-found-img-desk" src="./assets/img/not-found-desk.svg" alt=""/>
   <img class="not-found-img-mobile mx-auto" src="./assets/img/not-found-mobile.svg" alt=""/> </div>
```

Este es mi codigo

```
var notFound = document.getElementsByClassName("not-found")
    console.log(notFound)
    notFound.classList.remove("hidden")
    console.log(notFound)
```

Esta es la consola - Si pruebo add class pasa lo mismo. No entiendo donde esta el problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Add y remove funcionan, lo malo es que cuando usas el selector de clases, no recibes un elemento, si no una lista de elementos. si quieres añadirle una clase tendras que recorrer la lista y añadir la clase a cada elemento o solo al que tu quieras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he tenido la ocasión de probar el código pero creo que podría ser porque estás usando el método **getElementsByClassName** el cuál devuelve un array.

Si quieres aplicarlo solo a un elemento deberías usar **querySelector(.classname)**, este devolverá el primer elemento que encuentre con esa classname.

Por otro lado también podrías iterar sobre ese array y aplicar el add o el remove a cada uno de los elementos de este.